# Autocomplete (typeahead) on URL bar in firefox

Tags: firefox, search, typeahead

When I start typing in the url bar in firefox, it makes suggestions of url's based on my browsing history, which is great.

But google chrome, in addition to doing this, also makes suggestions of search terms -- just as it does when you type into the google search text field.

Any way to get firefox to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In about:preferences#search, you can select `Provide search suggestions` and `Show search suggestions in location bar results`.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/awesome-bar-search-firefox-bookmarks-history-tabs